# Boolean causes texture of object to be displayed in gap

Tags: animation, texturing, modifiers, boolean-modifier

I'm pretty new to blender and this is hard to explain.

I'm using a boolean to make a house look like it's rising up from the ground, but in some parts of the animation, you can see some texture between the parts of the house that aren't connected.

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, there's a weird texture connecting the sides of the house.
Is this some UV issue? Am I really dumb?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you had added a boolean modifier on the roof, when I disabled it, it went back to the normal texture. I thought you wanted to keep the modifier right, so I applied it instead, did the unwrap, and went into the uv editing to fix how the texture displays.

here is the [file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pPQCjvSgh2-fplPbc6MaWUn2Ij_FWE4h/view?usp=share_link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pPQCjvSgh2-fplPbc6MaWUn2Ij_FWE4h/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 0):

press the key tab (or go into edit mode [![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGclx.jpg Then select the part that don't look right, press the key "u" and click "unwrap"

for example, if you have a cube, it has 6 sides right? so instead of selecting all the sides and pressing the key "u", then do the unwrap, you will in most cases want to select one side by one.

If you don't seem to make it work, I recommended you upload the blender file and I'll take a look for you

Comment: I'm probably doing it wrong, but selecting the faces of the roof and unwrapping doesn't seem to do it.
If you could take a look, that would be great!
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BvJYlwLA_MwLXqP-YHoENXA3QNhFYt5d/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I just answered the question again!